# Basic fact about injections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm fishing for a proof of the following. I have one, but my right to left (i.e. assuming the property to show injectionhood) is a little clumsy.

The function $$f:X \to Y$$ is an ***injection*** iff for any *A, B* subsets of *X*: $$A \subset B \implies f(A) \subset f(B)$$To be clear, the above are *proper* subset relations.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: That's a definition, not a theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is an injection, then for any $A \subset B \subseteq X$, there is some $b \in B \setminus A$. If $f(A) = f(B)$, then there is some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = f(b) \in f(B)$, contradicting $f$ being an injection.

For the reverse inclusion, if $f$ is not injective, then there are some $a\neq b \in X$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$. Let $A = \{a\}$ and $B = \{a,b\}$. Both of these are subsets of $X$ and $A \subset B$, but $f(A) = f(B) = \{f(a)\}$.